# fractal in pyqt --> problems with recursion

Tags: python, recursion, pyqt, fractals

I am trying to draw this simple tree fractal without success...
I have tried many combinations to get the recursive working propperly but never seemed to succeed to get the shape I wanted.
Here is the code I got at the end.

```
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtWidgets, QtCore, Qt
import sys

class Arena(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Arena, self).__init__()
    self.angle = 45
    self.transform = QtGui.QTransform()
    self.translate2 =  0
    self.recursions = 10

    self.setGeometry(2500, 400, 500, 500)

    self.origin = (self.width()/2, self.height())
    self.pal = QtGui.QPalette()
    self.pal.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.Background, QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
    self.setPalette(self.pal)

    self.pen_branch = QtGui.QPen()
    self.pen_branch.setColor(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
```

initializes class

```
    self.init_UI()

def init_UI(self):
    self.slider_angle = QtWidgets.QSlider(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, self)
    self.slider_angle.setMinimum(-8000)
    self.slider_angle.setMaximum(8000)
    self.slider_angle.setGeometry(0, 50, self.width(), 50)
    self.slider_angle.valueChanged.connect(
        lambda value, x=0 : self.setAngleValue(value))
    self.setAngleValue(4500)
    self.slider_angle.setValue(4500)
```

builds the UI

```
def setAngleValue(self, value):
    self.angle = value/100
    self.update()
```

sets the angle

```
def branch(self, p, len):
    p.drawLine(0, 0, 0, -len)
    p.translate(0,-len)
    if len > 3:
        len *= 0.66

        self.transform = p.transform()
        p.rotate(self.angle)
        self.branch(p, len)
        p.setTransform(self.transform)

        self.transform = p.transform()
        p.rotate(-self.angle)
        p.translate(0, len)
        self.branch(p, len)
        p.setTransform(self.transform)
```

Here is where the magic of the fractal should happen: the recursive method (AFAIK ...)
I use 'p.transform' to grab the transformation matrix and restore it after I create the line.

```
def paintEvent(self, e):
    p = QtGui.QPainter(self)
    p.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing)
    p.setPen(self.pen_branch)
    p.drawText(20, 20,  'angle: ' + str(self.angle))
    p.drawText(100, 20,  'trans2: ' + str(self.translate2))


    # Trunk
    p.translate(self.width()/2, self.height())
    p.drawLine(0, 0, 0, -100)

    self.branch(p, 100)
```

The paint event that paints the lines on the canvas.

```
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
Arena = Arena()
Arena.show()
app.exec_()
```

The application runner.

After some fiddling I have reached a close result to what I am looking for but still not the goal yet. I'd like to create a perfectly symetrical tree, but this is what I got:

[image: fractal tree]

The new code is like this:

```
def branch(self, p, x, r, len):

    p.drawLine(0, 0, 0, -len)
    if len > 1 :
        p.translate(0, -len)
        p.rotate(r)
        self.branch(p, 10, self.angle, len * 0.66)

        p.rotate(-r)
        self.branch(p, 10, -self.angle, len * 0.66)
        p.translate(0, len)
        p.rotate(-r)

def paintEvent(self, e):
    p = QtGui.QPainter(self)
    p.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing)
    p.setPen(self.pen_branch)
    p.drawText(20, 20,  'angle: ' + str(self.angle))
    p.drawText(100, 20,  'trans2: ' + str(self.translate2))

    p.translate (self.width()/2, self.height())
    self.branch(p, 10, self.angle, 200)
```

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: Thanks @eyllanesc for your interest. I was getting totally fractally-liike random results. I changed the branch function to this but now I get a chopped off tree: not perfectly symmetrical as expected ...
I have added the new code and a picture at the end of the post ...

Comment: @Pau for future reference, please avoid using multiple snippets if they're part of the same code, it makes it harder to read and to copy/paste to try it out. If you need to add comments, use code comments instead. Also, avoid using setting geometries like those, not everybody has a screen as big as that.

Comment: Thanks @musicamante, I'll try my best next time. I had to split the code because stackoverflow was telling me that it was too long and I had to comment it ... I am sure there is a better way to do it :) Thanks for letting me know, I am new here and am sure I will have to learn a few new stackoverflow protocols :)

Comment: @Pau No harm done, anyway you don't need to split the code (or you can split it only when necessary), you can just add more details in the question: StackOverflow doesn't care about *where* the non-code parts are, it just has a limit for code/text ratio (for users with reputation <= 500). BTW, I posted an answer to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem resides in how the `branch` function is implemented: after you call `rotate` the first time, the other branch needs to use a *doubled* angle in order to go in the opposite direction.

Consider this: assuming the angle is 30°, if you call `rotate(r)` for the right branch, then you have to `rotate(-r * 2)` for the left one; in this way the angle is "reset" to the original value and then rotated on the opposite side.

This is the modified version of your function:

```
    def branch(self, p, x, r, length):

        p.drawLine(0, 0, 0, -length)
        if length > 1 :
            p.translate(0, -length)
            p.rotate(r)
            self.branch(p, 10, r, length * 0.66)

            # rotate to the opposite side
            p.rotate(-r * 2)
            self.branch(p, 10, -r, length * 0.66)
            # note that translation and rotation are inverted, opposed to your
            # example, this is because you translated first and *then* applied
            # rotation, so you should "reset" those states in the opposite way
            p.rotate(r)
            p.translate(0, length)
```

To avoid this kind of problems, it's usually better to use the [`save()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainter.html#save) and [`restore()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainter.html#restore) functions, which allow you to use multiple levels of painter states: you `save` a state, apply all modifications you want (pen, brush and *any* kind of transformation), then you can `restore` the previous state automatically; this makes development easier, and get a much more readable and understandable code; just remember that the states must *always* be *restored* up to the original saved "level".

Here is how a better `branch` function could look:

```
    def branch(self, p, x, r, length):
        p.drawLine(0, 0, 0, -length)
        if length > 3:
            # save state, first level (for the current function)
            p.save()
            p.translate(0, -length)

            # save state for the right branch
            p.save()
            p.rotate(r)
            self.branch(p, 10, r, length * .66)
            # restore to the previous "first" level
            p.restore()

            # again, for the left branch
            p.save()
            p.rotate(-r)
            self.branch(p, 10, -r, length * .66)
            # restore again
            p.restore()

            # restore the previous state
            p.restore()
```

And here's the result:

[image: screenshot of the fractal]

Some suggestions:

- use *descriptive* variables names (`p`, `x` and `r` are not very meaningful);
- never use built-ins for variable names (in your case, `len`);
- the lambda connection for `valueChanged` seems useless; what's the use of the `x` variable? Please try to keep your examples as minimal as possible, avoiding unnecessary variables or functions that just create confusion to the reader;
- use separated widgets for each task; create a main container (which might be the "top level window"), *set a layout manager*, then add the slider and the custom widget to it; avoid setting fixed geometries as much as possible: the UI should be able to adjust itself to the window size ("responsive", as we call it nowadays);

Comment: thank you very much for all your advice. I wanted to make this script simple, that is why I mixed everything in only one document, as what really interested my was to get the fractal algorythm right..
Whit that said, your advice is very cool, and the save() and restore() are really the way to go. Now I have exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot again :)